# Why can I see pip list sklearn but not in Jupyter when I run a code?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I am currently working on my first program with Jupyter. When I run a cell I receive the following

```
<ipython-input-6-7a7db0de4539> in <module>
      1 try:
----> 2     from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
      3     mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1, cache=True)

c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py in <module>
     63     from . import __check_build
---> 64     from .base import clone
     65     from .utils._show_versions import show_versions

c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in <module>
     12 from .externals import six
---> 13 from .utils.fixes import signature
     14 from . import __version__

c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py in <module>
     15 from ..exceptions import DataConversionWarning
---> 16 from .fixes import _Sequence as Sequence
     17 from .deprecation import deprecated

c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py in <module>
     84 else:
---> 85     from scipy.special import boxcox  # noqa
     86 

c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py in <module>
    640 
--> 641 from ._ufuncs import *
    642 

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I used pip install to get sklearn and when doing pip list in the cmd it is there. However when I even try import sklearn I get an error.

I have checked `import sys` then `sys.path` which gave me:

```
'C:\\Users\\James\\Documents\\Machine Learning Comp Vision\\Project 1',
 'C:\\Users\\James\\Documents\\Machine Learning Comp Vision\\Project 1',
 'c:\\users\\james\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\python37.zip',
 'c:\\users\\james\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\DLLs',
 'c:\\users\\james\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib',
 'c:\\users\\james\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37',
 '',
 'c:\\users\\james\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib\\site-packages',
 'c:\\users\\james\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
 'C:\\Users\\James\\.ipython']
```

All of my modules are located in `C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages`
Would the capital letters in my file url be the cause of this or is it something to do with the path itself?

Comment: how did you install sklearn?

Comment: pip install -U scikit-learn @Jeril

Comment: Likely, you do not have the appropriate kernel setup for your jupyter notebook. This often will happen when, say, you have multiple versions of python installed on your OS, or you are installing your packages to a virtualenv and jupyter doesn't have a kernel associated with that particular environment. What is the ouptut of `which python` from the terminal, and then `jupyter kernelspec list`?

Comment: For windows I generally download the libraries from [Unofficial Python binaries](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-learn), can you try installing numpy and sklearn from here.

Comment: @Eric I cannot run those commands I am on windows (I tried in jupyter and my cmd ).. My python is 3.7.2  and the kernel that the .ipynb file is on is python3

Comment: @Jeril should i uninstall then re install?  I ran without un installing and it says they already exist

Comment: For Windows cmd, use `where` instead of `which`.

Comment: yes you need to uninstall and then install. `pip uninstall ...`

Comment: @Jeril I did the uninstall and got this Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\
pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2584, in version
    return self._version
  File "c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\
pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2691, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _version

Comment: I got it to download but i get ^ in read when using cmd now.. it still does not work with re installed sklearn and numpy.

Comment: @gilch C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe is what I get when I typed {where python}

Comment: can you try this [link](https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/issues/355)

Comment: @Jeril I will try it first thing in the morning! thank you for helping me.

Comment: @James I am virtually certain your issue has to do with the kernel for your ipython notebook is not pointing to the environment that you are installing packages to. Unfortunately, I do not windows, so I cannot help you further.

Answer (score 0):

**If** you already have a **working** installation of **numpy** and **scipy**, then do this:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

otherwise:

```
conda install scikit-learn
```

finally check for updates:

```
conda update pip
```

Comment: i do not have conda.. should i download conda or can i just stick to python pip install

Comment: I have done so, but I believe this is a problem with the path of the kernel in jupyter after doing more research.

Answer (score 0):

Use pip from inside your Jupyter notebook

```
!{sys.executable} -m pip install -U scikit-learn
```

This will use the `sys.executable` to run the right pip for your current kernel, instead of for some other Python install.